# Getting error while trying to display image(blob object) in jsp (Spring and Hibernate with Oracle Database)

Tags: spring, hibernate, blob

This problem is with oracle 10g database. Same code is working fine with MySQL Database.

My Model Class

```
package com.killerlinks.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Blob;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Lob;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="links")
    public class Linkform implements Serializable
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;
        @Column(name="tittle")
        private String tittle;
        @Column(name="xdesc")
        private String desc;
        @Column(name="url")
        private String url;
        @Column(name="category")
        private String category;
        @Column(name="xdate")
        private String date;
        @Column(name="xtime")
        private String time;
        @Column(name="tags")
        private String tags;

        @Column(name="image")
        @Lob
        private Blob fileData;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getTittle() {
            return tittle;
        }
        public void setTittle(String tittle) {
            this.tittle = tittle;
        }
        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }
        public void setCategory(String category) {
            this.category = category;
        }
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }
        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }
        public String getTags() {
            return tags;
        }
        public void setTags(String tags) {
            this.tags = tags;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        { 
            return "Linkform [tittle=" + tittle + ", url=" + url + ", category="+ category +", tags="+ tags +", desc="+ desc +", fileData="+fileData+" ]";
        }
        public Blob getFileData() {
            return fileData;
        }
        public void setFileData(Blob fileData) {
            this.fileData = fileData;
        }
    }
```

This method from my controller class which helps to keep blob object to model class.

```
private Linkform preparingModelBean(LinkformBean linkformbean, MultipartFile file)
    {
        Linkform linkform = new Linkform();
        linkform.setTittle(linkformbean.getTittle());
        linkform.setUrl(linkformbean.getUrl());
        linkform.setCategory(linkformbean.getCategory());
        linkform.setDesc(linkformbean.getDesc());
        linkform.setTags(linkformbean.getTags());


        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
        SimpleDateFormat stime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");


        linkform.setDate(sdate.format(date));
        linkform.setTime(stime.format(date));

        try {
            Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());

            linkform.setFileData(blob);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return linkform;
    }
```

This is another method from controller class, where i am trying to read blob object

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/image/{id}")
    public String image(@PathVariable("id")Long id, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Linkform linkform = linkformservice.getALink(id);

        try {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +linkform.getTittle()+ "\"");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            IOUtils.copy(linkform.getFileData().getBinaryStream(), out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

when i am trying to call specific image this is output i am getting

[image: error message i am gettting]

When i trigger the url from the browser `http://localhost:7070/KillerLinks/image/381.htm`

this is the error displayed in my console

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getDBAccess(BLOB.java:955)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.lob.SerializableBlob.getBinaryStream(SerializableBlob.java:39)
    at com.killerlinks.controllers.CategoryController.image(CategoryController.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getDBAccess(BLOB.java:955)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.lob.SerializableBlob.getBinaryStream(SerializableBlob.java:39)
    at com.killerlinks.controllers.CategoryController.image(CategoryController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Hibernate: select linkform0_.id as id1_0_, linkform0_.category as category1_0_, linkform0_.xdate as xdate1_0_, linkform0_.xdesc as xdesc1_0_, linkform0_.image as image1_0_, linkform0_.tags as tags1_0_, linkform0_.xtime as xtime1_0_, linkform0_.tittle as tittle1_0_, linkform0_.url as url1_0_, linkform0_.xviews as xviews1_0_ from links linkform0_ where linkform0_.id=?
```

Please help me to fix the bug.
I want image to be displayed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the @Lob to @ Blob

Comment: @kris @ Blob is not available. should i add any jars for it.

Comment: Just a minute. I will be back, dont change to @Blob

Comment: @SKr you checked blob size when hibernate returns value. & also check at db side to view that image(to display correct or really error in image)

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/image/{id}")
    public void image(@PathVariable("id")Long id, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Linkform linkform = linkformservice.getALink(id);

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            IOUtils.copy(linkform.getFileData().getBinaryStream(), out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It will send your file to direct download.

In addition you can add image file to html page

```
<img src="/image/5"></img>
```

Comment: the code which you have given didnot work. When i used that code, it is downloading image with 0 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/image/{id}")
public void image(@PathVariable("id")Long id, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    Linkform linkform = linkformservice.getALink(id);
    InputStream image = null;
    image = linkform.getFileData().getBinaryStream();

    try {
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        int length = (int) image.available();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((length = image.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
           response.flushBuffer();
        //image.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but getting blank page. No output, Not even error(Just Blank Page).

Comment: if you dont want to download remove this code -  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +linkform.getTittle()+ "\""); See the updated answer, I am using a similar code to display image in jsp

Comment: i removed that line, but still same. No output, Not even error(Just Blank Page).

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the image from DB and image added to DB is in right format

Comment: you can check above my code. preparingModelBean method where i am inserting blob object.

Comment: Answer updated added code  response.flushBuffer(); try this also

Comment: It looks like the file is not set for some reasons, try setting a file from your local drive. Put some log in your controller method that is print the  length of the file ---  int length = (int) image.available();

Comment: i updated my Question please check. I tried printing the length. it is printing in preparinModelBean() method. But when i trying print in controller class in image() method, it is not printing.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other piece of code invoking **linkform.getFileData()**? If not, do you mind modifying your code a little bit like following.
Entity Class:

```
@Column(name="image")
@Lob
private Byte[] fileData;

public Byte[] getFileData() {
    return fileData;
}
public void setFileData(Byte[] fileData) {
     this.fileData = fileData;
}
```

And also change your controller based on new **getFileData()**.

I cannot guarantee that this solution would definitely solve your probleam, but it is worth giving it a go. The reason I am saying so is that the exception trace tells you code failed on opening an DB connection to load Blob data. And according to java doc, the **Interface Blob** is actually a logical pointer to underlying SQL Blob rather than holding real data. Since controller is out of hibernate session, it might not be able to open another connection to DB for retrieving Blob value.